# how to spring boot batch job running manually from command prompt

Tags: spring-boot

let us say : with out spring boot we can run like below:
$ java -cp "target/dependency-jars/*:target/your-project.jar" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner spring/batch/jobs/job-read-files.xml readJob

how do we run above same with out job-read-files.xml in spring boot. as i configured in JobReadFiles.java file with spring boot.?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your question , you want to run your code not using batch but manually . So to do that you can create an api which is going to call your method to perform certain action and than that api you can hit from browser or even from command prompt or you can set that job in task scheduler .
And in spite of keeping all your configuration in xml file you can use annotation @Schedule to make your job run at certain point in time .

Comment: can you share me how to check job is existing or not before running through API.

Comment: i used JobExplorer for list jobs. but it is showing null. share me simple example scenarion if possible.

Comment: if you are using linux environment and you are using individual project for job that you can check that using ps -ef | grep java or you can give the name of your specific project .if you are able to see pid than it means that your project is running or else you can verify from the logs as well . If its generating .
and like below code you can schedule it as well .

Comment: @Scheduled(cron="0 00 17 * * ?")
 public void CallQueryGoogleBooks(){
  limitComp = 0;
  isbnFlag = true;
  log.info("================SCHEDULED=========================");
  JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  java.util.List<String> isbn = googleIsbnDao.getISBNOrdBySalesRank();
  isbn.forEach(processedIsbn -> {
   try {
    if(isbnFlag){
    queryGoogleBooks(jsonFactory, processedIsbn);
you can go through this doc 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html